# Cannot create constants class

Tags: python, class

To better organize my code, I tried to create a constants class:

```py
class Constants:
    def __init__(self):
        Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
        Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
        Constants.WINDOW_COLOR = (100, 100, 100)

        Constants.TICKRATE = 60
        Constants.GAME_SPEED = .35

        Constants.LINE_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)
        Constants.ALINE_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

        Constants.BARRIER = 1
        Constants.BOUNCE_FUZZ = 0

        Constants.START_X = int(.5 * Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH)
        Constants.START_Y = int(.99 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT)

        Constants.AIR_DRAG = .3
```

When I try to call one of the constants, such as on this line:

```py
ball = Ball(Constants.START_X, Constants.START_Y)
```

I get this error: `AttributeError: type object 'Constants' has no attribute 'START_X'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class members in python are defined like this:

```
class Constants:
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
    WINDOW_COLOR = (100, 100, 100)

    TICKRATE = 60
    GAME_SPEED = .35

    LINE_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)
    ALINE_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

    BARRIER = 1
    BOUNCE_FUZZ = 0

    START_X = int(.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH)
    START_Y = int(.99 * SCREEN_HEIGHT)

    AIR_DRAG = .3
```

You can then access them using `Constants.START_X` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm locked out of voting and accepting for a little while, so I'll +1/accept tomorrow. You don't need the `__init__()`